# Underscore.js knowledge required

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have been going thru underscore.js lately. I have to send parameters in result()

```
 result_.result(object, property)
```

Here is my Code:

```
            var template = _.template($('#item-template').html());
            var templateData = {
             listTitle: "Olympic Volleyball Players",
             listItems: [
             {
                 name: "Misty May-Treanor",
                 hasOlympicGold: true,
                 links : "http://www.facebook.com"
             },
             {
                 name: "Kerri Walsh Jennings",
                 hasOlympicGold: true
             },
             {
                 name: "Jennifer Kessy",
                 hasOlympicGold: false
             },
             {
                 name: "April Ross",
                 hasOlympicGold: false
             }
             ]
         };
         var test_var = {name:'hello', func: test_func}
         var test_func = function(one, two){return one+two;}
            $('#target').append(template(templateData));
```

the problem is i cant call a function test_func with parameter(one, two) is there anyway to execute the function with its parameter?

Here is the template:

```
            <script type="text/html" id="item-template">
                <h2 class="hello"><%= listTitle %></h2>
                <% _.each(listItems, function(value, key, list){%>
                <% if(value.hasOlympicGold){ %>
                <% if(value.links !== undefined){ %>
                <li>Name: <a href="<%= value.links %>"><%=value.name%></a></li>
                <% } else {%>
                <li>Name: <%=value.name%></li>
                <%= _.result(test_var,'func')%>
                <% } %>
                <% } %>
                <% }) %>
                </script>
```

What should be done? please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the values onto your template Data. The scope is executed within a with statement, so those variables are not visible to the scope of the function.

```
var templateData = {
    test_var : test_var,
    test_func : test_func,
    listTitle: ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F38dg/

Comment: If you don't want templateData polluted by these objects create an object, put all three values in it and pass the new object. e.g.
`data = {test_var:test_var,test_func:test_func,templateData:templateData}`